# Where can I find stats on Android distribution (number of devices) by cpu?

Tags: android

As a developer of android application that implements part of its functionality using native code (c++), I would like to prioritize my effort based on a per cpu brand and architecture (e.g. ARMv6, ARMv7, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen Google publish statistics for this, only for platform version and screen details. I think you are outa luck.

I would imagine the majority are ARM7 or later, but that's just my estimate.